# R package 'biomod2' cannot find file when executing plot function

Tags: r, plot, path, biomod2

I am attempting to use the `plot()` function in the `biomod2` package, following a vignette here (http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/usr/share/doc/library/biomod2/doc/Simple_species_modelling.pdf).  Below is the error I am getting:

```
getwd() 
# [1] "/home/gjanzen/Documents/Hufford/Drought/Data/Layers"
plot(myBiomodData)
```

> Error in getExportedValue(pkg, name) :    cannot open file
>   '~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/viridisLite/data/Rdata.rdb': No
>   such file or directory  In addition: Warning message: In
>   getExportedValue(pkg, name) : restarting interrupted promise
>   evaluation

I have confirmed that the Rdata.rdb exists, in the following directory:

```
f <- file.choose()
f 
# [1] "/home/gjanzen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/viridisLite/data/Rdata.rdb"
```

So, to me, it looks like the `plot()` function is looking in the wrong place.  How can I change where this function looks for `Rdata.rdb`?  Can I alter the path somehow?  Or would changing my working directory fix this?

PS - This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so please forgive any mistakes in etiquette, and/or feel free to point them out to me so that I do not repeat them.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first thing to try is to reinstall the package `viridisLite` that seems to be the one that is causing troubles.

`install.packages('viridisLite', dep = TRUE)`

If this not solves the issue you should try to open a new plotting device threw x11() to check if the issue is not coming from the R (resp. RStudio) plotting device itself.